# Do weight paint and textures have no effect on manually added hair?

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

I want to create a beautiful parting of my hair.
So I tried to use Weight Paint and Textures to adjust the density of the hair I added manually, but it didn’t work.
Is it normal for this to not work?

Both weight paint and textures worked on the first hair that automatically grew evenly, not on the manually added hair.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: I am not even sure but why do you expect it to even work? You either make hairs with weight paint or you add them manually... I don't see the reason to use both possibilities at once and I am not sure if it is even supposed to work... if you need to remove hair you can manually cut them

Comment: Does this mean that vertex group density will not work for manually added hair?

Comment: Probably not... If you want to make whole mesh have one type of hair and other part (in weight paint) another type of hair added manually, then you need to make 1 vertex group for weight and 2 particle systems, one will be manual and one will be using weight painting as density